# How to change whole Grid's background color for specific row

Tags: xaml, uwp

Something similar to this:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Width="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

But this would change the whole Grid. I just want to change the background color of specific row. How?

Comment: you can place stackpanel on particular row and column and then give it background color which you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another Grid inside the Grid like this:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Width="300">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Background="Blue" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can replace the Grid to Border to improve some performance.